# VbScript unknown runtime error on opening workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript, runtime-error, qtp

I'm not able to open any-work while working with QTP using vbscript to open Excel workbook to read input data. History of the problem is as - on last weekend my organization decided to install Excel 2010 on my machine. After that, when i checked i had two version of Excel (2007 & 2010) installed on my machine which started the problem.

I removed excel 2010 and re-install excel 2007 but the problem is still persisting.
Code which is giving the error is while opening workbook as 'Unknown Runtime Exception'

```
completeFilePath = "C:\Users\rahul.singh\Desktop\TC1.xls"
gv_SanityTradeDataSheet = "TCFlow"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open(completeFilePath)
Set objDriverSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(gv_SanityTradeDataSheet)
wscript.echo objDriverSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

objWorkbook.Close
Set objDriverSheet = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Any idea what's the issue/fault and how to come out of it

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: just an update ... have discovered that execution machine in question here still have two different version of excels in it. Not sure how but it's present. Uninstalling it and will update if it helps

Comment: No Help on Uninstalling the complete Office suite and re-installing just a single version ( v. 2007 ) only. Not sure what's wrong. Error is coming while creating workbook object !!

Comment: Hi,i'm still not able to create to move ahead after creating an excel object through VBScript to use it further. 'code'            Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") XLApp.Visible = True
           Wait(5)'code'
Error comes in the second line itself and not on the first line. I'm kind of stuck and Re-install of MS Office also didn't help and getting out of options :(

Comment: Re-set QTP´s DCOM settings? Reinstall QTP?